# Update a form using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to update a form in my application using Ajax.BeginForm.
The updation is taking place but after executing the function in the controller it redirects to a view with the controller function name. I don't want it to redirect to another view instead I want to display an alert message like success or failure.

```
<div id="target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Insert", "User", new AjaxOptions{
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       UpdateTargetId = "target",
       OnSuccess = "success"
   }))
   {
       <ul>
       @foreach (var item2 in Model.sample)
       {
           <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="Contentpropclass" value="@item2.name">
               <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="@item2.id"/>
               <input type="hidden" value="@item2.name" name="Name" id="Name"/>
               @item2.name
               <input type="number" name="age"  value="@item2.age" placeholder="age"  />
               <input type="number" name="siblings" value="@item2.siblings" placeholder="" /> 
           </li>     
       }
       </ul>
       <br /> <br /> <br />
       <br /> <br /> <br />
       <br /> <br /> <br />

       <button type="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show controller action?

Comment: Have you included unobtrusive ajax javascript files in your view? It sounds like it's doing a syncronous call to your controller instead of making an ajax call. This most of the time happense due to javascript errors.

Comment: Now its showing success and failure message.Problem is that after saving,ajax reloads the form portion and it makes a box in which all the names will be listed then the normal li name with age and siblings box. And even the size of that div reduces. I want to remove that extra li and disable the size change.I want only success or faiure messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a JSON from your controller.

**c#**

```
public ActionResult Controller1(String postdata1, object postdata2)
        {
            Boolean result = GetResultMethot(); 
            var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

**cshtml**

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Insert", "User", new AjaxOptions{
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           UpdateTargetId = "target",
           OnSuccess = "AjaxResponse(data)"
       }))
```

**JavaScript**

```
function AjaxResponse(json) {
    if(json != null && json.length > 0 && json == "true")
    {
       alert("true");
    }
    else
    {
       alert("false");
    }   
}
```